# Read a <div> inside a <td> using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a HTML table like this.

```
<table class="gvi gvi-rentals" data-bind="css: { hide: empty }" id="tblRentals">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: rentals">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="chb">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Checked" value="false" data-bind="attr: { 'id': 'check_' + $index() }" />
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="multi-data">
                        <div class="col-product-id" name="ProductId" data-bind="text: ProductId" hidden></div>
                        <div class="col-product-name" data-bind="text: ProductName"></div>
                        <div class="col-serial-no" name="SerialNo" data-bind="text: SerialNo"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to read the values of all the `<div>` and put their values into an array. So I wrote a jQuery function as well.

```
$('#tblRentals tr').each(function () {
        var tds = $(this).find("#Checked").val();
        rentals.push({
            Checked: $('td input[name="Checked"]', this).val(),
            ProductId: $('td div[name="ProductId"]', this).val(),
            SerialNo: $('td div[name="SerialNo"]', this).val(),
        });
    });
```

It doesn't work and all I get is undefined. What is the mistake here?

Comment: Why do you want to get the values from HTML when you have databinding going on?

Comment: `tblRentals` isn't defined in your code.

Comment: @Robert I am guessing samithagun isn't the one who wrote the initial code (which is probably using Knockout), and he is tasked with fixing it while not wanting to learn Knockout.

Comment: @oligofren: I added that now. It was not the issue actually.

Comment: @Robert: Because I'm not good at knockout and I want to do a simple ajax post.

Comment: You probably don't want `.val()` on a checkbox (use `.is(":checked")`) and for `div`s you definitely want `.text()` not `.val()`.  Don't know if knockout changes that.

Comment: @freedomn-m: Of course it was the damn issue. What a silly mistake I have done. Thank you very much for figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code uses `.val()` to get the "value".

```
$('#tblRentals tr').each(function () {
    var tds = $(this).find("#Checked").val();
    rentals.push({
        Checked: $('td input[name="Checked"]', this).val(),
        ProductId: $('td div[name="ProductId"]', this).val(),
        SerialNo: $('td div[name="SerialNo"]', this).val(),
    });
});
```

This is only used on inputs (text/select), for a div, use `.text()` and for a checkbox use `.is(":checked")`.

```
$('#tblRentals tr').each(function () {
    var tds = $(this).find("#Checked").val();
    rentals.push({
        Checked: $('td input[name="Checked"]', this).is(":checked"),
        ProductId: $('td div[name="ProductId"]', this).text(),
        SerialNo: $('td div[name="SerialNo"]', this).text(),
    });
});
```

You could also use `.html()` for `div`s if you need formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know knockout js but I tried to rectify your jquery code.

> Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var rentals = [];
  $('#tblRentals tbody tr').each(function() {
    var Checked = $(this).find("td:eq(0) span input[name=Checked]").is(":checked");
    var ProductId = $(this).find(".multi-data .col-product-id").text();
    var ProductName = $(this).find(".multi-data .col-product-name").text();
    var SerialNo = $(this).find(".multi-data .col-serial-no").text();
    rentals.push({
      "Checked": Checked,
      "ProductId": ProductId,
      "ProductName": ProductName,
      "SerialNo": SerialNo
    })

  });
  console.log(rentals);
});
```

> HTML

```
<table class="gvi gvi-rentals" data-bind="css: { hide: empty }" id="tblRentals">
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: rentals">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="chb">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Checked" value="false" data-bind="attr: { 'id': 'check_' + $index() }" />
                        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="multi-data">
        <div class="col-product-id" name="ProductId" data-bind="text: ProductId" hidden></div>
        <div class="col-product-name" data-bind="text: ProductName"></div>
        <div class="col-serial-no" name="SerialNo" data-bind="text: SerialNo"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope it will probably help you.